# Empty union existence? A basis for the topology

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Consider $(X, \tau)$ where $$\tau = \{\emptyset, X, \{a \}, \{c\}, \{a,c \},\{a,b \},\{b,c \} \},$$

and the nonbasis $$B = \{ \{a\}, \{c\},\{a,b\},\{ b,c\}  \}.$$

My book says $\emptyset$ can be generated by an "empty union of memebers in $B$". I take it they mean $$\emptyset = \cup \emptyset.$$

But how can this happen when $\emptyset \notin B$?

Comment: Note that $\tau$ is not a topology, it misses the intersection $\{a,b\}\cap\{b,c\}$. What do you mean by "nonbasis" ?

Comment: @StefanHamcke, I mean it is not a basis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subset $S \subseteq B$, is itself a set of subsets of the topological space $X$; then $\bigcup S$ is the subset of $X$ consisting of those elements which lie in some set in $S$.

More precisely, if $S \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ then
$$\bigcup S = \{ x \in X : x \in U\ \text{for some}\ U \in S \}$$

Now $\varnothing \subseteq S$ since the empty set is the subset of every set (so it's definitely a subset of $S$). And
$$\bigcup \varnothing = \{ x \in X : x \in U\ \text{for some}\ U \in \varnothing \}$$

But no $U \in \varnothing$ even *exist*, so we must have
$$\bigcup \varnothing = \varnothing$$

If it's the notation you're confused about, bear in mind that, for example,
$$A \cup B = \bigcup \{ A, B \}$$
Hopefully some of the waffle I've given above clears up your confusion.

Comment: That kind of answered my question, but would it be wrong to include $\emptyset \in B$?

Comment: It would be wrong to conclude $\varnothing \in B$. $B$ has four elements, and none of them are $\varnothing$. (It is true that $\varnothing \subseteq B$ though.)

Comment: No, "include", not "conclude". So is it wrong to put the empty set inside $B$ is what I am asking.

Comment: @sidht: Well what's $B$ meant to be? Are you asking if it becomes a basis when you put $\varnothing \in B$?

Comment: No, I am asking if it is okay to write $$B = \{ \emptyset, \{a\}, \{c\},\{a,b\},\{ b,c\}  \}.$$

Comment: @sidht: In that case my first comment *did* answer your question. It's false to say that, because $B$ is fixed, you're given what it is, it has four element and none of its elements are the empty set.

Comment: I know it's given. BUt I was asking if $B$ was given like what I wrote, is it still okay?